# what actually a session object contains?

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
    session=request.getsession(true);
    System.out.println(session)
```

What will be the output of the above code please explain those things in the output

Answer (score 0):

session's `toString()` method will get called and that will be printed.

Comment: Every time when logging out and logging again is the output will be different?

Comment: because new session is created each time when you logout and do `session.invalidate()`